# Replace html content without replacing the tags or attributes - PHP

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace

How can i replace  content inside or outside HTML dom without replacing the HTML tags or attributes?

e.g

```
$txt='good <div class="good">good</div>'
$search='good';
$pattern      = '#(?!<.*?)(\b'.$search.'\b)(?![^<>]*?>)#si'; 
$replacement  = 'nice';
$txt = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $txt);
```

So i will like it to output `nice <div class="good">nice</div>` and ignore the `good` inside any attributes because the tags and attributes are dynamics which i will not know, this is just example.

Comment: I guess you do realize that it's hard with regular expressions. Why? Because it's a job for a parser to find text nodes and not regular expressions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the dom:

```
$txt='good <div class="good">good</div>';
$search = 'good';
$replace  = 'nice';

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($txt, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

foreach ($xpath->query('//text()') as $text) {
    if (trim($text->nodeValue)) {
        $text->nodeValue = str_replace($search,$replace, $text->nodeValue);
   }
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: Good approach, I'd just change the xpath, `$xpath->query('//div[contains(@class,"good")]')`.

Comment: This outputs a spurious `<p>` tag around the original html https://3v4l.org/18Lke

Comment: `$txt='<span id="good">good</span>good <div class="good">good</div> ';` gives wrong output `<span id="good">nice<p>nice </p><div class="good">nice</div></span>` https://3v4l.org/BUoZl

Comment: i removed `LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED` from `$dom->loadHTML($txt,LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);` and also use preg_replace `$html=preg_replace(array("/(^<html>|<\/html>$)/i","/(^<body>|<\/body>$)/i"), "", $dom->saveHTML());` to remove the first html and body tag from the html and it then works perfectly as required. Thanks alot!  https://3v4l.org/LJ5aq

Comment: I don't see `str_replace()` being necessary for the asked question.